# Работа с ключами. Python

Tags: python

Есть код, по нему надо вывести все элементы с значением 'holiday weekend', 'preholiday', а также удалить все элементы со значением 'workday' и 'weekend'. Как это можно сделать?

```
[{'2022-01-01': 'weekend', '2022-01-02': 'weekend', '2022-01-03': 'holiday weekend', '2022-01-04': 'preholiday', '2022-03-05': 'preholiday', '2022-03-10': 'workday', '2022-03-11': 'workday'}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так:

```py
data = {'2022-01-01': 'weekend', '2022-01-02': 'weekend', '2022-01-03': 'holiday weekend', '2022-01-04': 'preholiday', '2022-03-05': 'preholiday', '2022-03-10': 'workday', '2022-03-11': 'workday'}

# проходим по каждому ключу в data
for elem in list(data):
    if data[elem] in ('holiday weekend', 'preholiday'):
        print(elem)
    if data[elem] in ('workday', 'weekend'):
        data.pop(elem)

print(data)
```

**Выхлоп:**

```py
2022-01-03
2022-01-04
2022-03-05
{'2022-01-03': 'holiday weekend', '2022-01-04': 'preholiday', '2022-03-05': 'preholiday'}
```